# Using Python to Union two polygons from separate gdb?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.2

I'm in the processes of learning python and am stuck on an exercise. One part of the exercise requires me to union a polygon from one gdb with a polygon in another gdb.

Here is what I have, which isn't working:

```
arcpy.Union_analysis(in_features="polygonA #;polygonB #",out_feature_class="C:test.gdb/union",join_attributes="ALL",cluster_tolerance="#",gaps="GAPS")
```

So polygonA is from one gdb, while polygonB is from test.gdb.
I feel like I should put the pathway for polygonA in, but I'm not quite sure how to do so.

I'm using ArcMap 10.2.2.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved.

```
arcpy.Union_analysis([r"C:\database.gdb\polygonA","polygonB"],"C:/test.gdb/union",join_attributes="ALL",cluster_tolerance="#",gaps="GAPS")
```

Slight syntax changes fixed the issue. The addition of brackets and the removal of "in_features" and "out_feature_class" fixed the issue.

Comment: Yes, that's it, if you have set arcpy.env.workspace then names without paths are searched in the workspace - anything else needs the full path.